# Native Camera feed Maui implementation

Tags: c#, android, camera, maui

I am developing a cross-platform app in MAUI Blazor. It MUST HAVE custom camera that, i think, has to be necessarily programmed separately for android and ios to get full control of each device capabilities.

To open the camera app is not a valid solution for this case.

So i am wondering, how can i write the xaml files so that they take the prefixes that are linked to the c# code that controls the camera for android.

From this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextureView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello, I am a Button" />
    
    <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
                 android:src="@Resources/camera"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

To something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             x:Class="AndroidCamera.Pages.Camera1">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <Button Text="Hello"/>
            
            <Label Text="Hello World"
                   BackgroundColor="red"/>
            
            <Button android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:Text="Hello, I am a Button" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
       
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Note that in this last example, i have "id", "layout_width", "layout_height" and "Text" in red and not working, so i guess something is not working with the namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either write native code or JavaScript to control cameras in .NET MAUI Blazor.

- **C#**: You need to implement platform-specific classes for Android and iOS. Microsoft provides a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view) demonstrating how to create a custom renderer. According to the tutorial, I implemented camera access in .NET MAUI:

  - [Android CameraPreviewRenderer](https://github.com/yushulx/dotnet-barcode-qr-code-sdk/blob/main/example/maui/Platforms/Android/CameraPreviewRenderer.cs)
  - [iOS CameraPreviewRenderer](https://github.com/yushulx/dotnet-barcode-qr-code-sdk/blob/main/example/maui/Platforms/iOS/CameraPreviewRenderer.cs)

  [image]
- **JavaScript**: You can put HTML video element in a `razor` file and implement camera access in a separate JavaScript file. Try out this example: https://github.com/yushulx/DotNet-MAUI-Blazor-Barcode-Scanner.

I've deployed the blazor code to GitHub pages: https://yushulx.me/blazor-barcode-qrcode-reader-scanner/.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the first way is how we did it. We have the whole project in razor except the camera, which runs on xaml because we could not get the razor-camera feed to work. If i am not mistaken you cant get access to whitebalance, focus, torch and so on with JS, right?

Comment: @Dakxin as of now, JavaScript API can only toggle torch :)

Answer (score 0):

I did a simple test, if opening the camera from within the app cannot fully access the saturation, zoom, whitebalance, etc.. it can only access a few of them. If you want to access these, you can jump directly to the local camera in the app, refer to the following code:

```
Intent startapp = PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.camera");
                StartActivity(startapp);
```

Comment: The camera view has to be custom made, and so, I am not allowed to open the camera app directly. Thats why i thought i had to code native...

Comment: In Maui you can have partial classes and partial methods that call platform code from cross-platform code. You can refer to the official documentation: [Invoke platform code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code?view=net-maui-7.0). Once a platform implementation is provided, the API can be called from cross-platform code in Maui by creating an object instance and calling its operations.